# Processing a very long single line of comma-separated (?) floating point numbers

Tags: bash, console, floating-point, awk, sed

I have a sample svg file from the graphics program Inkscape. My objective is to collect every third pair from a very long line of floating point numbers. That seems simple enough. The larger objective is to write out svg code with calculated parameters - because Inkscape cannot do this in a "batch" mode - only "by hand" - all fine and doable.

I have a lengthy script (not shown) that gets the correct result, using `bash, awk, grep, cut` and `sed` - because I have a lot of such scripts to work from. I have looked at many other posts on Unix & Linux, which had some promise. Perhaps a single `python` or `perl` script would be better to write `svg` output, but I am trying to focus on individual steps of the ad-hoc script that works - the initial `grep/sed/awk` part - to make this appropriate for Stack Exchange.

The numbers are separated (if that is the correct word) by a comma, like this :

`0.05306,-1.85438`

I suppose I should show the line I am working on, apologies for the length. I am trying to preserve everything - including the leading spaces :

```
       d="m 53.049246,151.83874 c 0.05306,-1.85438 0.155553,-3.63727 0.304925,-5.35109 0.153133,-1.75698 0.355536,-3.44137 0.604459,-
5.05582 0.257082,-1.66737 0.563784,-3.26013 0.917074,-4.78117 0.399178,-1.7186 0.857832,-3.34565 1.371592,-4.88532 0.566073,-1.69644 
1.199045,-3.2868 1.893068,-4.77667 0.733396,-1.57438 1.534967,-3.03655 2.397812,-4.39309 0.897172,-1.4105 1.86059,-2.70681 2.882498,-
3.89632 1.158647,-1.34869 2.392483,-2.56009 3.690201,-3.64502 1.232816,-1.03066 2.523284,-1.94718 3.861711,-2.75883 1.457388,-0.88378
 2.97164,-1.6432 4.53024,-2.29024 1.538451,-0.63866 3.120112,-1.16782 4.732946,-1.59897 1.636238,-0.4374 3.304561,-0.77392 4.992402,-
1.02158 1.640903,-0.24077 3.300254,-0.39755 4.966504,-0.48136 1.661534,-0.0836 3.329929,-0.0946 4.993735,-0.044 1.679345,0.0511 3.354
014,0.16488 5.012237,0.33022 1.63047,0.16257 3.24504,0.37495 4.83252,0.62644 1.7341,0.27473 3.43586,0.59612 5.09071,0.95025 1.65289,0
.35371 3.25896,0.74008 4.80369,1.14522 1.69385,0.44425 3.31394,0.91106 4.8411,1.38213 1.64731,0.50813 3.1865,1.02121 4.59351,1.51626 
1.8366,0.6462 3.44798,1.26167 4.78064,1.79531 2.67181,1.06986 4.22329,1.81076 4.22329,1.81076"
```

... I note there are some letters in there too - in fact, the first pair has to be skipped - see the `sed` command. So the next step in this script is to get the remaining pairs. The following works but seems a terrible way to do it - because ideally, the processing script should handle any `svg` file Inkscape might produce :

```
input=for_script_test_01.svg
grep "\ d=" $input  | sed 's/^.\{33\}//' | sed 's/\"//g' | \
awk '{print $3, $6, $9, $12, $15, $18, $21, $24, $27, $30, $33, $36, $39, $42, $45, $48, $51, $54, $57, $60, $63, $66, $69, $72, $75, $78}'
```

the output is :

```
0.304925,-5.35109 0.604459,-5.05582 0.917074,-4.78117 1.371592,-4.88532 1.893068,-4.77667 2.397812,-4.39309 2.882498,-3.89632 3.690201,-3.64502 3.861711,-2.75883 4.53024,-2.29024 4.732946,-1.59897 4.992402,-1.02158 4.966504,-0.48136 4.993735,-0.044 5.012237,0.33022 4.83252,0.62644 5.09071,0.95025 4.80369,1.14522 4.8411,1.38213 4.59351,1.51626 4.78064,1.79531 4.22329,1.81076
```

that is clumsy to read - and might have typos even though I checked - so I tried to put the pairs in a single column using a clumsy one-liner on the output file `> output.dat` (note: the `each $each` is a typo, should be `echo $each`, but we are leaving it be):

```
user@local:/home$ my_list=`cat output.dat` ; for each in $my_list ; do each $each ; done
```

the last three lines of the output, to check :

```
4.59351,1.51626
4.78064,1.79531
4.22329,1.81076
```

... apologies for length. Hopefully the idea is clear.

UPDATE : this post on extracting path strings and lines from svg files using some svg parser modules in python will be helpful for working this out :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857818/python-svg-parser

[Related post on Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160239/inkscape-dots-points-on-a-curve-line-x-y-coordinates-of-points-in-svg-file)

Comment: does this work as intended? if not stackoverflow is probably the place to ask

Comment: it works and the larger script works - it calculates positions of circles to put in an svg - but I think that is beyond the scope here. I could have put the output but it is so long, I figured users can just run the one-liner to check. perhaps I'll put the last line.

Comment: ... thank you, I discovered a typo - a ```.``` instead of a ```,``` in the```awk``` call. I adjusted and added some output.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw apologies, perhaps I could put a note around it.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is a very powerful programming language. If you plan to invoke it, you likely need neither `grep` nor `sed`.

`sed` is also a very powerful programming language. Assuming you already got the payload

```
0.155553,-3.63727 0.304925,-5.35109 0.153133,-1.75698 0.355536,-3.44137 0.604459,-5.05582 0.257082,-1.66737 0.563784,-3.26013 0.917074,-4.78117 0.399178,-1.7186 0.857832,-3.34565 1.371592,-4.88532 0.566073,-1.69644 1.199045,-3.2868 1.893068,-4.77667 0.733396,-1.57438 1.534967,-3.03655 2.397812,-4.39309 0.897172,-1.4105 1.86059,-2.70681 2.882498,-3.89632 1.158647,-1.34869 2.392483,-2.56009 3.690201,-3.64502 1.232816,-1.03066 2.523284,-1.94718 3.861711,-2.75883 1.457388,-0.88378 2.97164,-1.6432 4.53024,-2.29024 1.538451,-0.63866 3.120112,-1.16782 4.732946,-1.59897 1.636238,-0.4374 3.304561,-0.77392 4.992402,-1.02158 1.640903,-0.24077 3.300254,-0.39755 4.966504,-0.48136 1.661534,-0.0836 3.329929,-0.0946 4.993735,-0.044 1.679345,0.0511 3.354014,0.16488 5.012237,0.33022 1.63047,0.16257 3.24504,0.37495 4.83252,0.62644 1.7341,0.27473 3.43586,0.59612 5.09071,0.95025 1.65289,0.35371 3.25896,0.74008 4.80369,1.14522 1.69385,0.44425 3.31394,0.91106 4.8411,1.38213 1.64731,0.50813 3.1865,1.02121 4.59351,1.51626 1.8366,0.6462 3.44798,1.26167 4.78064,1.79531 2.67181,1.06986 4.22329,1.81076 4.22329,1.81076"
```

then

```
sed 's/[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\)./\1\
/g'
```

produces

```
0.304925,-5.35109
0.604459,-5.05582
0.917074,-4.78117
1.371592,-4.88532
1.893068,-4.77667
2.397812,-4.39309
2.882498,-3.89632
3.690201,-3.64502
3.861711,-2.75883
4.53024,-2.29024
4.732946,-1.59897
4.992402,-1.02158
4.966504,-0.48136
4.993735,-0.044
5.012237,0.33022
4.83252,0.62644
5.09071,0.95025
4.80369,1.14522
4.8411,1.38213
4.59351,1.51626
4.78064,1.79531
4.22329,1.81076
```

Specifically, it replaces every three space-separated "words" with the last one, followed by a newline (if you have a GNU sed, a literal newline is not necessary: `\n` will suffice).

To extract the payload, use `sed -n '/d=/s/[^m]*m [^ ]* c [^ ]* \(["]*\)"/\1/p'`

Comment: excellent - in the first example command what is ```.``` and ```\1``` called or what are they doing (so I can find it in ```info sed```)?

Comment: ...and in the second ```sed``` example, even if I do not suppress printing (```-n```) I do not see anything changing. Every "word" (as ```sed``` knows them) is preserved, so I think I am missing something...

Comment: Re `\1`, pay attention to the `\(...\)`. The latter is a _capture_. `\1` prints the first capture, in thiks case the third word.`g`' does it `g`lobally.

Comment: so to print the 4th  pair, we specify : ```[^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).```, to print the nth pair, we write n-1 of ```[^ ]*``` followed by the ```\([^ ]*\).```

Comment: ...  also note the spaces - so ```[^ ]*     [^ ]*``` will just pass right over the interesting bits, as the input only has one space, as in the middle of this: ```digits,digits digits,digits```

Comment: for the "extract the payload" one-liner, I assume that is to improve upon the clumsy ```grep``` in the original question. I experimented with the one-liner. I do not grasp the use of ```-n```. When run on various _whole_ ```svg``` files, the one-liner seems to print the entire file (with no ```-n```given). Admittedly I only wrote the pre-extracted line in this question. It is ideal to get only the line with ```d="m``` and so on, and leave the other stuff alone.

Answer (score 1):

The question as stated is still open, but in the meantime, I found an alternative way around this problem, the source code of which one might look at for clues:

Use the program `svg-path-interpolator` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850680/how-to-extract-the-cartesian-coordinates-x-y-of-an-svg-image), or the website alternative. In particular for this problem, I found a way to use `awk` to fix up the output - but not precisely as requested. Perhaps a clue might be found in it. But the overall objective is achieved with this.

So reading the linked question/answer on how to use `svg-path-interpolator` (there are other pitfalls I describe [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638425/node-js-and-javascript-library-script-example-no-output)), we take the example `svg` file above, and do the following (possible error : it looks like `(i%2?$i:$i)` should be `$i`) :

```
svgpi.mjs config.json for_script_test_01.svg | \
gawk -F, '
{
  gsub(/{|}|]/, "") ;
  gsub("\"[a-z]{4}_?([0-9]{1,14})?\":\\\[","") ;
  {
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  printf("%3.6f%s", (i%2?$i:$i), i%2?",":"\n")
  }
}' > for_script_test_01_coords.dat
```

the `svgpi` output (one line, 2351 characters by `wc`) is shown here. Nine `x,y` pairs, a hand-edit trim, then a trailing two `x,y` pairs, then a `]}` cap - for illustration purposes only :

```
{"path857":[53,151.25,53,150.75,53,150.25,53,149.75,53,149.25,53,148.75,53,148.25,53,147.75,53.25,147.25[...snip...]132.75,116,133.25,116.25]}
```

The `awk` script above (I thank `comp.lang.awk` for help with that) converts the `svgpi` output into `gnuplot`-friendly form (for instance - beyond the scope), of which the first nine lines look like this:

```
53.000000,151.250000
53.000000,150.750000
53.000000,150.250000
53.000000,149.750000
53.000000,149.250000
53.000000,148.750000
53.000000,148.250000
53.000000,147.750000
53.250000,147.250000
[...snip...]
```

If anyone goes to do this, bear in mind that quadratics (`q` in the `svg`'s `path`) might give strange results, so read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820497/tool-library-to-convert-svg-paths-cuves-from-quadratic-to-cubic) which says to use `cairosvg` to approximate them with cubics.

So this answer is more of a work-around, but based on what I learned in the intervening days since asking the basic question about getting "every third pair of (numbers)" (still working on that).

Comment: I also learned by now this question and answer isn't really what is called for by the Code Review Stack Exchange guidelines, but figured I'd follow through for completeness instead of ditching it.